# Error with Dispatcher Thread in a Module

Tags: c#, multithreading

A typical multithreading problem I've come across:

> This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread

Ordinarily, I'd solve this using one of these:

```
App.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)delegate
  {
  // Offending code goes in here. 
  });
```

However, this particular program is a module that gets loaded as a tabbed item in a larger program.  App is in the app.xaml.cs of the parent program, which I don't have access to from here.  Any ideas for a work-around or a different method?

Comment: Please try to explain what happens  in the code dispatcher should run

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always use the [`Application.Current`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.current%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property to access the Dispatcher:

```
System.Windows.Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)() => 
{
     // your code
});
```